# Can I invoke an operation of a JMX-MBean multiple times?

Tags: jmx, invoke, operation, mbeans

I have an application using JMX. In this application i have a MBean with one attribute and one operation. When I invoke the operation i get the message "Method successfully invoked". Now my question is, if it is possible to invoke this operation multiple times. Because after the call of this operation and i can't invoke it a second time.

Many thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you can't invoke the op a second time, but there is typically no limit on the number of times an op can be invoked.

Having said that, you have provided no details on the issue so it's difficult to help you.

Comment: I have found the problem mate. It was a problem in my business logic so thats the reason why nothing happened when I invoked it a second time. What a fault...sorry